# left join from a group of tables to another group of tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have some tables say t1 , t2 , t3.
I need to implement something like this in postgresql.

```
select * from (t1 , t2) left join t3
where t1.some_column = t3.some_column;
```

But postgresql complains

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "," SQL state: 42601 Character: 77

Comment: Consult [the excellent manual about the SELECT statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) and about [joining tables in the FROM clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) And if that does not help, come back and ask a proper question where you *explain* what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `from (t1,t2)`, you have to join them in some way.

Try something like this:

```
select * from t1
inner join t2 on t1.someColumn=t2.someColumn
left join t3 on t1.some_column = t3.some_column;
```

Comment: select * from t1
inner join t2 
left join t3 on t1.some_column = t3.some_column;

Comment: no. I meant for you to join them in some way. If you remove the on, the results will probably be way more than you expect, since that is a cartesian product of both tables. Explain a little better what you are trying to do. Is it a [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/typeconv-union-case.html) between t1 and t2 and left join that with t3??